# Is it possible to wrap a GNU Scientific Library function in emacs-lisp?

Tags: elisp, ffi, gsl

Is it possible to wrap foreign functions in emacs-lisp? I am interested in doing something like this from the GNU Scientific Library:

```
(let ((A '((0.18 0.60 0.57 0.96)
           (0.41 0.24 0.99 0.58)
           (0.14 0.30 0.97 0.66)
           (0.51 0.13 0.19 0.85)))
      (b '(1 2 3 4)))
  (gsl-linalg-LU-solve A b))
```

Returns (-4.05205 -12.6056 1.66091 8.69377)

If this is not possible, are there other ways to get numerical methods into emacs-lisp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, linking of any binary libraries that are not directly supported by emacs is not possible. Some time ago I read somewhere that this is intended behavior of emacs to avoid unexpected crashes. I do not know the exact source for this statement anymore. (Help of others is appreceated.)

The help for the variable `dynamic-library-alist` suggests it:

> > Alist of dynamic libraries vs external files implementing them.
> >     ...
> >     Also note that this is not a generic facility for accessing external
> >     libraries; only those already known by Emacs will be loaded.

Nevertheless, the calc package provides numerical algorithms. See e.g.,
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Vector-and-Matrix-Arithmetic.html
for LU decomposition.

A possible way out could be to use `call-process` or `start-process` with executable programs that run the matrix operations and to communicate with these programs over `stdin` and `stdout`.

Comment: I have had some luck with Pymacs (http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2014/10/19/Using-Pymacs-to-integrate-Python-into-Emacs/), but eventually I hit a wall with it and it doesn't seem to be developed anymore.  I suppose one could simply have emacs write a script and run it ;)